# How to set PATH when starting an Add In from Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook-addin

I am developing a C# Add-In for Word. In this code, I need to start an application, which is available in the `%PATH%`, when installed. However, on a development system, this application may not be available or I simply want to use the version under development, not the installed one. Is there a way to set the `%PATH%` (otherwise another variable) that my program can use when launched from Visual Studio (2015)?

Comment: Already tried with [Pre-build Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165412.aspx)?

Comment: @MatSnow No, but I fail to understand how a build event will set the PATH when debugging; am I missing something?

Comment: Everytime when you start debugging VS will build your project. But it seems "SET" is not working for your needs because it will run in a own shell an set the environment variable local only. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564981/visual-studio-pre-build-events-and-batch-set

Comment: Unlike c++ projects you cannot set the environment just for the executable which gets debugged. Easiest way is to start devenv.exe from a commandline with the proper environment variables set (like in the answer MastSnw linked). Or you could write a cutom msbuild task calling Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable for the process (devenv.exe in this case) environment, and it wil be inherited by the exe started under the debugger. But then just starting devenv from a proper environment is way easier.

Comment: @stijn Uggg I don't know if I should laugh or cry... Thanks for the explanation.